# Determining which Macro/Executable I am running in Guardian on an HP Non Stop machine

Tags: hp-nonstop

There is a macro (TACL) version of a utility and an executable version. In fact, there are several Macro versions. I would like to change my environment so when I enter the name it runs the executable rather than the Macro.  So let's say the macro is $SYSTEM.MACROS.RunMe and the executable is $SYSTEM.SYSEXE.RunMe. I would like to know if there is a way to tell which will run when I just enter RunMe at the command line? and I want to understand what I need to change to make it be $SYSTEM.SYSEXE.RunMe?

Thanks for your time on this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the second question is to set the TACL variable #PMSEARCHLIST so that the subvol you want the executable to run from is before any subvol containing the macro. You can do this in (say) TACLCSTM.

Use #OUTPUTV #PMSEARCHLIST to maybe get some clue to answer the first question.

Comment: This answer is essentially true, what I ultimately found the macro had been loaded as a routine, so I had to create variable reference to the executable to avoid the Marco. thanks.